# Pure CSS menu with highlighting the page which I am presently on

Tags: css, menu

I am trying to make a purely css / html structure for menu which has background of the active menu link page with a different color. For that I am using the `:checked` selector.  I am able to make this happen by clicking on the input elements but when I click on the actual links themselves, nothing happens.

I do not want to have the menu code in every page of the menu and have included it in a include file. Please tell what I am not doing right. I do not want to use javascript / jquery for this purpose.

*Edit* -

These are separate pages with separate links. I kept all the links same so as not to go outside my codepen.

This is my codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPrOoj and this is my snippet -

```css
.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(248, 220, 192, 1);
    color: black;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li.nav_bar {
    display: inline;
    padding: 1% 0% .5% 0.75%;
    border-right: solid 1px rgba(78, 52, 25, 1);
 flex-grow: 1;
}
.nav ul li a {
    color: black;
 display: block;
 
}
.nav ul li.active {
     background-color: rgba(103, 140, 57, 1);
  
}
.nav ul li.active a {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
 color : #ccc;
}
.nav ul li.nav_bar:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
a.nav_bar {
    text-align: center;

    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
}
a.nav_bar:hover {
    color: red;
}
.menu1:checked ~ ul.nav_bar>.num1+li.first {
  background: blue;
}
.menu2:checked ~ ul.nav_bar>.num2+li.second {
  background: red;
}
.menu3:checked ~ ul.nav_bar>.num3+li.third {
  background: pink;
}
.menu4:checked ~ ul.nav_bar>.num4+li.fourth {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" >
<input class="menu1" id="_menu1" type="checkbox">
  <input class="menu2" id="_menu2" type="checkbox">
  <input class="menu3" id="_menu3" type="checkbox">
  <input class="menu4" id="_menu4" type="checkbox">
  
 <ul id="respons-text1" class="nav_bar">
    <label class="num1" for="_menu1">
<span></span></label>
  <li class="nav_bar active first"><a class="nav_bar" href="#">home</a>
  </li>
    <label class="num2" for="_menu2">
<span></span></label>
  <li class="nav_bar second"><a class="nav_bar" href="#">about</a>
  </li>
    <label class="num3" for="_menu3">
<span></span></label>
  <li class="nav_bar third"><a class="nav_bar" href="#">work areas</a>
  </li>
    <label class="num4" for="_menu4">
<span></span></label>
  <li class="nav_bar fourth"><a class="nav_bar" href="#">contact</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you cannot achieve that without javascript because when you load a new page there is no way that you can maintain the correct checkbox checked unless you repeat the checkboxes in each page and put the checked attribute to the correct input. The Pen it's not working well anyway. This is only HTML and CSS or you are using a database? If it's the case you can retrieve the current page and assigning classes dynamically to the current page...

Comment: This is only HTML and CSS. Menu items are not fetched from database.

Answer (score 2):

The Codepen you link to *can* be made with CSS only. However, it *still* doesn't get around the issue of when the new page loads, there's no way to know which nav item is active.

Here's the CSS-only solution to highlighting an active nav item. I've used the same setup you started with so the links stay highlighted even after other page elements are clicked (which would not happen if we used `:focus`).

```css
body{
  font-sze:14px;
}

.container{
 max-width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
nav ul li{
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  padding-right:20px;
}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#222;
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding:4px 5px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + a {
  background-color:#d90000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navecation">
      <ul id="navi">
        <li><input name="nav" type="radio" id="about"><a class="menu" href="#"><label for="about">About</label></a></li>
        <li><input name="nav" type="radio" id="contact"><a class="menu" href="#"><label for="contact">Contact</label></a></li>
        <li><input name="nav" type="radio" id="services"><a class="menu" href="#"><label for="services">Services</label></a></li>
        <li><input name="nav" type="radio" id="contactus"><a class="menu" href="#"><label for="contactus">Contact Us</label></a></li>
        <li><input name="nav" type="radio" id="blog"><a class="menu" href="#"><label for="blog">Read Our Blog</a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <body>
```

Comment: Goal is to have a css menu with links and the page which I am on to be highlighted in the menu bar. So, the links are needed, I cannot remove that.  I tried wrapping the `li` with the `label` but that messes up the styling completely.

Comment: But why the checkboxes and labels?

Comment: The checkboxes and labels are for using the `:checked` css selector property. The checkboxes will be hidden.

Comment: And the point of using the `:checked` CSS property is to highlight the links?

Comment: Yes, I want to highlight the menu item for the page I am presently on.

Comment: Is this a single page app? Or the links go to actual new pages?

Comment: These are separate pages with separate links. I kept all the links same so as not to go outside my codepen.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the problem, but the checkbox/label setup doesn't seem it will solve the problem. The main problem will be getting the URL path when the next page loads. And checkboxes/labels won't help with that.

Comment: The `:active` selector kinda does what you want, without all the extra markup of checkboxes and labels. But again, doesn't solve the problem of knowing which page is active based on the current URL.

Comment: This is what I want but without the javascript / jquery - https://codepen.io/arjunamgain/pen/lGALt

Comment: I've updated my solution with a CSS-only solution of that Coden. But again, the problem of knowing which page should be active when a new page loads is still present.

Comment: O.k. I think this cannot be acheived by only Css. As i do not want to use javascript/jquery, I have to use php. For example - https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php-include-menu-class-active-css/11412/8

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been trying to get at. What you want to do _is_ possible with some simple PHP. Just add an `active` class to the current path, and style the `active` class with the background color. That Codepen you linked to does almost exactly what you want. Just remove the JS, then add some PHP to add the extra `active` class on the current link.